# What EXCEPTION can be added to this function in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

This function is used to return the total number of orders for a shopper using their ID.  Every time I try to throw an exception, nothing happens.  It will return a null value.  For example, IDSHOPPER = 19 does not exist within BB_BASKET, so I was thinking that I could throw an exception if lv_total_orders = 0, but it was still returning a null value and DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE would not show anything in the output. Could anyone suggest how to throw an exception for this function if I were to use a IDSHOPPER that does not exist in BB_BASAKET?  This is for homework for my class, but I have done most of the work except for the exception which is required.  I cannot find anything that suggests how to execute an exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NUM_PURCH_SF
  (p_shopper IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
lv_total_orders NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM(ORDERPLACED)
     INTO lv_total_orders
     FROM BB_BASKET
     WHERE IDSHOPPER = p_shopper
     AND ORDERPLACED = 1;
RETURN lv_total_orders;
END;


SELECT NUM_PURCH_SF(IDSHOPPER)
  FROM BB_SHOPPER
  WHERE IDSHOPPER = 23;
```

Comment: [Raising Exceptions Explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-error-handling.htm#LNPLS00705)

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation functions always returns single row, even if no rows match the condition. You can look at [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm/)

So, if you want to throw exception, you can use [raising exceptions explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00705).
In your code, before return statement:

```
  if lv_total_orders is null then 
     raise_application_error(-20200, 'No data found for given ShopperID, ShopperID: ' || p_shopper);
  end if;
```